# Cannot boot from USB livedisk on HP Spectre x360 2020 13-aw2025na

Tags: boot, usb

I cannot get this device to boot from a Live USB due to the error :

```
stdin: Invalid Argument.
```

There is also an error about TPM chip before that, but I think thats unrelated.

I have tried the USB in another laptop and it works fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRTuv.jpg

I have disabled fast boot, secure boot and the tpm device, but I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a different USB and it worked this time, I'm not sure why the first one did not work (It worked in a different PC, just not this new one).

For info this was the original USB that did not work

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00YFI1EBC/

and this was the USB that did work :

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07B8WC2NT